# VS Code open extension host with file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently I'm writing my first extension for VS Code. Is it possible to specify a folder which is opened every time on the extension host after pressing `F5`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was just a click away:

There is a subfolder called `.vscode`. There `launch.json` can configure the opening options.

Comment: What configuration did you end up using to accomplish this?

Comment: I too am stuck on this. I've tried the following solution, but with no luck.

`"args": [ "${workspaceFolder}/my-workspace",  ... ]`

EDIT: Typical, Now it works